# Need to put the B's and W's on the corresponding chessboard spaces

Tags: java, chess

I've gotten closer but I just can't figure it out.  I'm not great in Java.  I know that the missing B's and W's are there, it's just that they are the same colour as the background.  If anyone can help, it would be great.

```
public class checktest2 { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int N = 8;
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, 8);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 8);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if ( (i % 2) == (j % 2) )
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
                else 
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                StdDraw.filledSquare(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, 0.5);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                  if ( (i % 2) == (j % 2) )
                    StdDraw.text(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, "W");
                  else
                    StdDraw.text(i + 0.5, j + 0.5, "B");
            }

        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, if you try to display a black character on a black background, that is going to be really hard to read.

Why don't you just select slightly different colors for the squares, so the "pieces" stand out better. Just like other programs do for their chess graphics.

Check this page, for example:

http://www.tim-mann.org/xboard.html